# Choose pronunciation for word when multiple pronunciations exist - SpeechSynthesisUtterance of JavaScript Web Speech API

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

When using a [SpeechSynthesisUtterance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance) from the Web Speech API, is it possible to choose the pronunciation of a word if multiple pronunciations exists.

For example: "live" in "I live here" and "A live event" are pronounced differently.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is unfortunately not possible.